# ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8

I got this error when try to upload a CSV file. The file is already ".csv" but why does Ruby tell me that it is an "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"? How do I force Ruby to upload this file without converting it again to UTF-8?

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/Users/usrname/workspace/apps_folder/lib/tasks/download_csv.rake:173:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/usrname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/usrname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => remote_file:fetch
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Please provide your code.

Comment: It appears that ruby thinks that your file isn't valid UTF-8, and it's probably right about that.

Comment: Ruby v1.9+ treats text files it's reading as UTF-8. The CSV format doesn't care whether the contents are ASCII, UTF-8 or some other encoding. You need to tell Ruby the appropriate encoding.

Comment: @theTinMan how do i tell ruby the appropriate encoding is it like `CSV.foreach(filename_path, headers: true, encoding: "UTF-32BE:UTF-8") do |row| `

Comment: nevermind i've figure out already. thanks for the help guys

Comment: @haziqhafizuddin What was the solution?

Comment: @AdrianMann i just force change the encoding before uploading the file like this 
file_cvs_handler = File.open(destination_path+'file.csv')
file_csv = file_cvs_handler.read.encode!("utf-8", "utf-8", invalid: :replace)
CSV.parse(file_csv, headers: true) do |row|

and it works.